# Redux Persist and Redux's initialState is clashing

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, persistence, react-redux

I'm currently using `Redux Persist` to persist my Redux state for React Native. Currently using AsyncStorage for that.
The problem is that I'm required to have an `initialState` for my Redux Reducer or else I get an error.

When the app starts, instead of getting the persisted data where I'm logged in, I get the `initialState` where I'm logged out instead.

Somehow after manually navigating to another page which is connected to the store, I get my persisted data back.

So I'm just having this `initialState` somehow preventing my persisted data.
If I remove `initialState`, then Redux gives an error that I must provide an `initialState` for my reducer.
Is there any workaround for this?

Edited:

Store.js:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist';
import Config from '../Config/DebugSettings';
import RehydrationServices from '../Services/RehydrationServices';
import ReduxPersist from '../Config/ReduxPersist';

// creates the store
export default (rootReducer) => {
  /* ------------- Redux Configuration ------------- */

  const middleware = []; //currently none
  const enhancers = [];

  /* ------------- Assemble Middleware ------------- */

  enhancers.push(applyMiddleware(...middleware))

  /* ------------- AutoRehydrate Enhancer ------------- */

  // add the autoRehydrate enhancer
  if (ReduxPersist.active) {
    enhancers.push(autoRehydrate())
  }

  // in dev mode, we'll create the store through Reactotron
  const createAppropriateStore = __DEV__ ? console.tron.createStore : createStore
  const store = createAppropriateStore(rootReducer, compose(...enhancers))

  // configure persistStore and check reducer version number
  if (ReduxPersist.active) {
    RehydrationServices.updateReducers(store)
  }

  return store
}
```

Comment: Can you post your store setup code? sounds like something might just be written in the wrong order.

Comment: @azium I've added my setup code

Comment: Curious if and how you resolved this issue...